# Getting multiple response data into array type javascript variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Can anyone kindly help me..? I created function to collect all supplier data from database.. and my function is working.. but now I want to create array type javascript variable to store those recored..
As example - supplier_id in one array type variable.. supplier_name in another array type variable.. like this..

```
function LoadSuppliers() {  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/supplier/getSupplier',
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);   
        
        }, error: function(data) {
        console.log('something went wrong!');
        }
    });
}
```

[image: And this is my response like..]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well if I got the question right, if you want to map the properties into an array you could use the `map` function.

For example:

```
var supplier_ids = response.results.map(function (item) { return item.supplier_id; });
```

Comment: Thank you very much..! It worked.. bt few modifications were according to codegrepper  ///////var supplier_data = response.data.result.map((array) => ({ img: array.address, id: array.supplier_id, value: array.supplier_name }));
            var supplier_data = response.data.result.map(function (array) { return {img: array.address, id: array.supplier_id, value: array.supplier_name}; });